# Swift. Incorrect slider value in player (YTPlayerView) with YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper. Slider can't get to the end

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, uislider, ytplayerview

Incorrect slider value in player (YTPlayerView) with YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper.

Slider can't get to the end.

Video is over, but my custom slider stop and don't get end its value.

[image: screenshot]

Where I'm wrong?

**I'll put some cut of code and functions (if need more, please say):**

```
class PlayerViewController: UIViewController, YTPlayerViewDelegate {

var durationOfVideo: Double?

lazy var rewindSlider: UISlider = {
    let slider = UISlider()
    slider.minimumTrackTintColor = .white
    slider.maximumTrackTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 0.7)
    slider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "Thumb_On_ProgressLine"), for: .normal)
    slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSliderChange), for: .valueChanged)
    
    return slider
}()

@objc func handleSliderChange() {
    print(rewindSlider.value)
}

// MARK: viewDidLoad

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    webView.delegate = self
    webView.load(withVideoId: "kbMqWXnpXcA",
                 playerVars: ["playsinline": 1])
}

// MARK: Player control

func playerViewDidBecomeReady(_ playerView: YTPlayerView) {
    playerView.duration { (time, error) in
        print("duration: \(time)")
        self.durationOfVideo = time
    }
}

func playerView(_ playerView: YTPlayerView, didPlayTime playTime: Float) {
    
    guard durationOfVideo != nil else { return }
    self.rewindSlider.value = Float((Double(playTime) / durationOfVideo!))

}
```